# In this diagram, why does the limit exist on this interval?

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits

Does the $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)$ exist at every point $x_0$ in $(-1,1)?$
I answered False, but the correct answer is True. Why?

My thoughts:

$f(x)$ is not the same number as $x \rightarrow 1$ from the right and from the left, and as $x \rightarrow -1$, only the righthand limit exists. $x=0$ is the only place where the righthand and lefthand limits exist.

[image]

Comment: The function is continuous on that interval, so the limit exists.

Comment: But $-1$ and $1 \not \in (-1,1)$.

Comment: $-1$ and $1$ are not in the interval $(-1,1)$, so you should not consider them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuity is a *pointwise* condition for a function.  You have to speak of a function $f$ being continuous *at* $x = x_0$, which as you know, means
$$
\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0).
$$

The interval notation with the round brackets denotes an open interval (one that does not include its endpoints):
$$
(-1, 1) = \left\{ x \in \mathbb{R} \;\big|\; -1 < x < 1 \right\}.
$$

The fact that $f$ is not continuous at $x = 1$ *(you're right)* has no bearing on whether the function is continuous at every point in the interval $(-1, 1)$.  **(It is.)**